# Why does NFKC normalize of all digits not work?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, locale, normalize

In `JavaScript` I am using `NFKC` normalization via `String.prototype.normalize` to normalize fullwidth to standard ASCII halfwidth characters.

```
'１'.normalize('NFKC') === '1'
> true
```

However, looking at more obscure digits like ૫ [which is the digit 5 in Gujarati](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0AEB) it does not normalize.

```
'૫'.normalize('NFKC') === '5'
> false
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Characters can be marked as not being subject to normalization, and that's apparently one of them.

Comment: If you want to get digits, unicode provides also number conversion tables.

Comment: @Pointy interesting.. is there anyway to know if a character is marked that way?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I cannot find what you are referring to, can you elaborate? Is this something that JavaScript has the ability to leverage?

Answer (score 1):

Unicode normalisation is meant for characters that are variants of each other, not for every set of characters that might have similar meanings.

The character ‘１’ (FULLWIDTH DIGIT ONE) is essentially just the character ‘1’ (DIGIT ONE) with slightly different styling and would not have been encoded if it was not necessary for compatibility. They are – in some contexts – completely interchangeable, so the former was assigned a decomposition mapping to the latter. The character ‘૫’ (GUJARATI DIGIT FIVE) does not have a decomposition mapping because it is not a variant of any other character; it is its own distinct thing.

You can consult the Unicode Character Database to see which characters decompose and which (i.e. most of them) don’t. The link to the tool you posted as part of your question shows you for example that ૫ does not change under any form of Unicode normalisation.

Comment: It seems like the examples I posted should be variants with the same meaning but different visual appearance just the fullwidth digit one vs digit one. There is no difference. They are compatible, just not canonical in Unicode terms.

Comment: From the official Unicode documentation: `Compatibility equivalence is a weaker type of equivalence between characters or sequences of characters which represent the same abstract character (or sequence of abstract characters), but which may have distinct visual appearances or behaviors.`

Comment: @AdamThompson I'm not an expert by any means but the way I've read the (generally opaque) spec it's about normalizing to a *recognizable* common base. A Gujarati-speaking person would not recognize "5" as being the same as that character, so to normalize that to "5" would not make sense. What (totally making this up) *might* make sense would be to normalize between similar characters in two closely-related languages.

Comment: @Pointy interesting, that would make sense. The spec does say: `The visual appearances of the compatibility equivalent forms typically constitute a subset of the expected range of visual appearances of the character (or sequence of characters) they are equivalent to.` which corroborates what you are saying. However they also say that `these variant forms may represent a visual distinction that is significant in some textual contexts, but not in others.`

Comment: It's super-vague, but I guess when you're describing a spec that's supposed to deal with the complete set of world writing systems stuff gets challenging.

Comment: The crucial difference is that ૫ is not based on the symbol 5. The Gujarati digits are not just the Arabic digits with a slightly different font applied – there are no “global default” numerals that everything else has to subordinate to. The Hiragana letter ん does not decompose to the Latin letter n either, for instance, just because they typically represent similar phonemes. If anything, the Gujarati digits would probably decompose to the Devanagari digits rather than ASCII characters under this broader concept of normalisation, since that is where they historically derive from.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking the wrong problem.

Unicode is main purpose is about encoding characters (without loosing information). Fonts and other programs should be able to interpret such characters and give a glyph (according combination code point, nearby characters, and other characteristics outside code points [like language, epoch, font characteristic [script and non-script, uppercase, italic, etc changes how to combine characters and ligature (and also glyph form).

There are two main normalization (canonical and compatible) [and two variant: decomposed, and composed when possible]. Canonical normalization remove unneeded characters (repetition) and order composing characters in a standard way. Compatible normalization remove "compatible characters": characters that are in Unicode just not to lose information on converting to and from other charset.

Some digits (like small 2 exponent) have compatible character as normal digit (this is a formatting question, unicode is not about formatting). But on the other cases, digits in different characters should be keep ad different characters.

That was about normalization.

But you want to get the numeric value of a unicode character (warning: it could depends on other characters, position, etc.).

Unicode database provides also such property.

With Javascript, you may use [unicode-properties javasript package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unicode-properties), which provide you also the function `getNumericValue(codePoint)`. This packages seems to use efficient compression of database, but so I don't know how fast it could be. The database is huge.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is looking for transliteration, really. They used a digit for an example, and digits do have a numerical value, but I have a feeling that they also want to "normalise" other characters, say αλφάβητο, to ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

The NFKC which you are using here stands for Compatibility Decomposition followed by Canonical Composition, which in trivial english means first break things to smaller more often used symbols and then combine them to find the equivalent simpler character. For example ->0, ﬁ->fi (Codepoint ﬁ=64257).
It does not do conversion to ASCII, for example in ख़(2393)-> ख़([2326, 2364])

Reference:https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms
For simpler understanding:https://towardsdatascience.com/difference-between-nfd-nfc-nfkd-and-nfkc-explained-with-python-code-e2631f96ae6c